# Using Nsubstitute for mocking a private method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I'm trying to test a class private method without changing the behaviour of the class.

I'm using nsubstitute to mock and set the result of the method.

```
public class CarTool : ICarTool
{
   private readonly IExternalService _extService;

   public CarTool (IExternalService extService)
   {
      _extService= extService;
   }

   public TechnicalDetailsWrapper GetTechnicalReview(string user_id)
   {
      var carList = _extService.GetCars(user_id);
      var newCarList = FilterAndSortCars(carList);
      var technicalDetails = GetTechnicalDetails(newCarList); <-- PRIVATE METHOD TO TEST

      return new TechnicalDetailsWrapper(){ TecnicalDetails = technicalDetails};
   }

   public virtual CarList FilterAndSortCars(args){ ... }
   
   private TechicalDatails GetTechnicalDetails(arg)
   {
      //logic to test
   }
}
```

Since the method I want to test (GetTechnicalDetails) is private.
I defined what the previous method (FilterAndSortCars) should return and then I check the result of whole method (GetTechnicalReview).

```
TEST
//arrange
   _extService = Substitute.For<IExternalService>();
   _carTool= Substitute.ForPartsOf<CarTool>(_extService);

   var testCarList = new ..//I build something meaningful for a test
   _extService.GetCars(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(new CarList()); //just to have default return value
   _carTool.FilterAndSortCars(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(testCarList); 
//act
   var result = _carTool.GetTechnicalReview("");
//assert
   ....
```

To do this I had to mark FilterAndSortCars as public and virtual just to control the input object of GetTechnicalDetails.

Seems to me a little bit overkill.